# How to disable upgrade mode in windows installer so that the user is always forced to uninstall before reinstalling

Tags: windows-installer, upgrade, installshield

How to disable upgrade mode in windows installer so that the user is always forced to uninstall before re-installing. This is because the upgrade may fail in numerous scenarios which we might not want to handle. Are there any `RESINSTALLMODE` options that can be changed for this?

Answer (score 1):

InstallShield's project template by default results in an MSI that uses the Minor Upgrade strategy.  A MajorUpgrade rule is not defined.

Simply navigate to  Media | Upgrades | Prepare Setup For Upgrade Scenarios | Upgrade Windows Installer Setup

On the common tab change Small/Minor Upgrade Settings from Prompt to Disable.

Assuming you haven't built up any automation to change the ProductCode from build to build, every MSI will be a Small/Minor upgrade and Setup.exe (if generated)  will tell the user to perform an uninstall.  If Setup.exe is not generated, Windows Installer will give an error message informing the user another version of the product is already installed and it needs to be removed first.

Answer (score -1):

You can block this in two ways. First, you can block in the new MSI when it detects the old MSI. To do this, you use the `ActionProperty` you define in the `Upgrade` table. I'll use WiX syntax since I know that best (translate to your tool as desired):

```
<Upgrade Id='PUT-YOUR-UPGRADECODE-HERE'>
   <UpgradeVersion Maximum='YourProductVersionHere' Property='OLDPRODUCTSFOUND' />
</Upgrade>

<CustomAction Id='ErrorWhenOldProductFound'
              Error='Please, uninstall previous versions of [ProductName] before continuing' />
<InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action='ErrorWhenOldProductFound'>NOT Installed AND OLDPRODUCTSFOUND</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

The following is easy syntax in the WiX v3.5+ toolset to do the same:

```
<MajorUpgrade DisallowUpgradeErrorMessage='Please, uninstall previous versions of [ProductName] before continuing' />
```

Second option is to block the upgrade in the old MSI *if* you add this before you ship.  The `UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE` Property is set in the old MSI, so we can create a launch condition on that. Again, WiX syntax would look like (translate to your tool as desired):

```
<Condition Message="[ProductName] cannot be upgraded, please uninstall it manually.">
   Installed OR UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE
</Condition>
```

Comment: how to do the same in Installshield

Comment: @Rob - None of this should be needed.  See answer below for InstallShield instructions.

Comment: It was an experiment to see if translating concepts from WiX to InstallShield make sense. I think the experiment was a pretty resounding failure. :)

Comment: InstallShield natively lacks a ProductCode="*".  You have to have build automation in place to gen a GUID (Latest MSBuild can do this nicely in the .ISPROJ) to support Major Upgrades.  If supporting Major Upgrades,  you can write an Upgrade rule and schedule error custom actions as suggested.   It all translates, but very few people have the overlapping WiX / MSI / IS knowledge to know how to do so. Hence my moniker of ISWIX. :)